# How to chain api calls, and loop until object is equal to specific value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do something that seems pretty trivial.

1. Call an API to start a job, which returns to an 'ID'
2. I need to monitor that job ID, for a specific status from the Json data. Status = "RUNNING" , or "DONE" This can take like 10 seconds to finish the state
3. When the job is in the "DONE" State, hit another end point to gather my json data.

I can do all this from postman without a problem, implementing it in javascript has proven to be quite hard.

I have attempted to use promises, call backs etc. At this point I think I have thoroughly confused myself. The question I guess really is, does someone happen to have an example of doing something like this with javascript, or am I using the wrong tool?

```
ID = apicall1();
status = apicall2();
if(status !== DONE){
GOTO status=apicall2();
}
else{apicall3()}

async function apicall1(){
return request(options, function (error, response){
if(error) throw new error(error);
}
async function apicall2(){
return request(options, function (error, response){
if(error) throw new error(error);
}

async function apicall3(){
return request(options, function (error, response){
if(error) throw new error(error);
}
```

Comment: What is `request`? Is this from [this deprecated package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)?

Comment: Yep, technically request-promise as the url I am using didnt have a valid ssl cert and couldnt work around that with fetch

Comment: Can you find an [alternative](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143)? I am not going to answer referencing a deprecated library.